# how to convert pdf file to text file using c#.net

Tags: c#, pdf

currently i have been using the following code and i am using some dll files from pdfbox

```
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("c://aa.pdf");

        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file.FullName);

        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        string text = pdfStripper.getText (doc);
        richTextBox1.Text = qq;
```

using this code i can able to get text file but not in a correct format plz give me a some ideas

Comment: What do you mean by "not in a correct format"? What exactly is wrong with it? Generally speaking, it's not easy to extract plain text from a PDF file, because the PDF document doesn't always store the text in the same way that it appears in the document so PDFTextStripper probably just makes a "best guess".

Comment: arrangement of the words were different

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the text from a pdf file is anything but trivial.

To quote from th iTextSharp tutorial.

> "The pdf format is just a canvas where
>   text and graphics are placed without
>   any structure information. As such
>   there aren't any 'iText-objects' in a
>   PDF file. In each page there will
>   probably be a number of 'Strings', but
>   you can't reconstruct a phrase or a
>   paragraph using these strings. There
>   are probably a number of lines drawn,
>   but you can't retrieve a Table-object
>   based on these lines. In short:
>   parsing the content of a PDF-file is
>   NOT POSSIBLE with iText."

There are several commercial applications which claim to be able to do it. Caveat Emptor.

There is also a free software library called Poppler http://poppler.freedesktop.org/ which is used by the pdf viewers of GNOME and KDE. It has a function called pdftotext() but I have no experience with it. It may be your best free option.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be a hard problem. I take it you're not creating these pdfs yourself?

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog article explaining the issues with PDF text extraction in general at http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/12670/PDF-text